# Can't find or load the platform plugin "windows"

Tags: qt, dll

I tried to make an installer for my QtCreator projet

It work perfectly on my computer, but when I tried to install it somewhere else it give me the following message

> This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".

here's the list of my .dll already in the dir

```
icudt52.dll
icuin52.dll
icuuc52.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Nework.dll
Qt5Quick.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
qwindows.dll
```

Do someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qwindows.dll` should be in `platforms` directory.

```
icudt52.dll
icuin52.dll
icuuc52.dll
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Core.dll
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5Nework.dll
Qt5Quick.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll
platforms/qwindows.dll
```